# Mysql complicated query

Tags: mysql

I have a bidding table in my app, and I need to figure out the Average number of bids per user over the last 6 months.  The table info is as follows:

```
  `bid_id` int(10) 
  `catalog_item_id`
  `customer_id` int(10)  
  `amount` decimal(9,2)  
  `date_modified` datetime
```

So essentially I need to use a `where date_modified > "2012-07-31"` to limit the last 6 months and then somehow group by each 6 of those months and 1) count the bids and how many users bid, and then i'll do the math of the avg off our total bidders.

Does that even make sense? Is my approach wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: >Does that even make sense?  - Not to me. Give some DDL (create and inserts) to work with

Comment: You mean like [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`bid_id`) `bids_per_month`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT `customer_id`) `bidders_per_month`, 
       COUNT(`bid_id`)/COUNT(DISTINCT `customer_id`) `avg_per_month`,
       YEAR(`date_modified`) `year`, MONTH(`date_modified`) `month` 
  FROM bids
 WHERE DATE(`date_modified`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
 GROUP BY `year`, `month`
```

Obviously `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` can be replaced with static date `'2012-07-31'`

Comment: @jahrichie Is that what you wanted? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: thanks for the help! this looks like what i wanted.  What i was trying was MUCH more complicated, thank  god for your help.